# Appending items to list in for cycle

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to append items to an empty list in for cycle:

```
pointList = {};
For[n = 1, n <= 10, n++, Append[pointList, {n, Sum[(-1)^(i + 1) * Binomial[n, i] * (n - i)! / n!, {i, 1, n}]}]];
```

But the pointList after the for loop is empty. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want AppendTo[], however you can do better here with a table :

```
pointlist=Table[{n, Sum[(-1)^(i + 1) * Binomial[n, i] * (n - i)! / n!, {i, 1, n}]},{n,10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that by definition of the Binomial function `Binomial[n,i]*(n-i)!/n!=1/i!`. Moreover, the sum simplifies via `FullSimplify[Sum[(-1)^(i+1)/i!,{i,1,n}],Assumptions->n>0]` to `1-Subfactorial[n]/n!`. Hence,

```
pointlist=Table[{n,1-Subfactorial[n]/n!},{n,1,10}]
```